# What is the Data value of plus sign in Path

Tags: wpf, path, shapes

How to draw plus and minus signs in using data property in Path object.

This is my triangle path object. I need to change it to plus symbol.

```
<Path x:Name="trianglePath"  Data="M 0 8 H 12 V 15 Z"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here, I've created a plus and minus sign which is 10 x 10 pixels using XAML path markup syntax:

```
<Path Margin="10" Stroke="White" Data="M0,5 H10 M5,5 V10Z"  StrokeThickness="2" Height="10" Width="10" />

<Path Margin="10" Stroke="White" Data="M0,5 H10"  StrokeThickness="2" Height="10" Width="10" />
```

When experimenting with designing your path drawing, it's helpful to set the path element's height & width first.  To better understand  XAML path markup syntax, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).

Comment: For plus it should be "M0,5 H10 M5,0 V10" i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier if you draw them out on a piece of graph paper and then label the vertices with the values needed to reach it from the previous one.

Then copy this into your code.