# How to draw a plus sign and triangles for buttons in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking to use the shape functionality in WPF in order to apply two triangles one pointing up and the other pointing down along with the plus sign to some buttons. Having a look there doesn't seem to be an easy to do this. Does anyone have an example where this can be easily done?

Thanks

Comment: go back and accept answers to your previous questions before you ask new questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Path mini-language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). For example a triangle pointing upwards could be created using the following path data:

```
M 0,0 l 8,0 l -4,8
```

Also, take a look at this very similar question:

[What is the Data value of plus sign in Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467484/what-is-the-data-value-of-plus-sign-in-path)